# How to get symbols names from ELF binary using C?

Tags: c, symbols, elf

I'm trying to read the symbols names from an ELF binary using the two functions below,
but I don't know if this is the right way to do it.

`Elf64_Shdr *get_shdr(void *ptr, char *name)` function gives me the address of the section header of the target section with name `name`.

`void elf64(void *ptr)` is simply used to print the symbols names, and you can see that I targeted the section `.strtab` specificly and not `.shstrtab`.

I understand the difference between `.strtab` and `.shstrtab` sections. The first is associated with the section `.symtab` and it contains the names of the symbols as refered in https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf, and the second is the section that contains the names of all sections in the ELF binary (Please correct me if I was wrong).

```
Elf64_Shdr  *get_shdr(void *ptr, char *name)
{
    int         idx;
    Elf64_Ehdr  *ehdr;
    Elf64_Shdr  *shdr;
    Elf64_Shdr  *shstrtab;

    if (ptr && name)
    {
        idx = -1;
        ehdr = (Elf64_Ehdr *)ptr;
        shdr = (Elf64_Shdr *)(ptr + ehdr->e_shoff);
        shstrtab = &shdr[ehdr->e_shstrndx];
        while (++idx < ehdr->e_shnum)
        {
            if (!strcmp(ptr + shstrtab->sh_offset + shdr[idx].sh_name, name))
                return (&shdr[idx]);
        }
    }
    return (NULL);
}

void    elf64(void *ptr)
{
    int         i, name;
    Elf64_Shdr  *symtab;
    Elf64_Shdr  *strtab;

    symtab = get_shdr(ptr, ".symtab");
    strtab = get_shdr(ptr, ".strtab");

    i = -1;
    while (++i < symtab->sh_size / sizeof(Elf64_Sym))
    {
        if (name > 0)
            printf("%s\n", (char *)(ptr + strtab->sh_offset + symtab[i].sh_name));
    }
}
```

If the code in the second function is not the proper way to read the symbols names, how would I do it instead?

Comment: The code seems correct. Why are you asking this question -- is it not working for you?

Answer (score -1):

ELF is complex enough to justify writting a library just for it.  Indeed there's one LGPL library that allows you to access ELF (and many other binary formats), so I recommend you to use it, as it handles all the idiosyncracies of all the binary formats (including `COFF`, `a.out`, etc) and you'll operate correctly in a way that's independent on the architecture, word length, endianness, etc.

The BFD library is part of the [binutils GNU package](http://sourceware.org/binutils/).  I'd look there before starting to dig into the details of ELF files to implement whatever you need is.

The only need you have is to `#include <bfd.h>` the proper library files and link with the appropiate `-lbfd` option, if you have the library installed (which you'll have, if you have installed the `binutils-dev` package)

Unfortunately I have seen no man pages or textinfo files in the installed packages, so you have to look up [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/bfd-2.9.1/html_mono/bfd.html) for documentation on it.

Also, if you don't want to deal with the library, there's still an alternative to parsing the file yourself.  You can process the output of tne `nm(1)` command, which shows you that information.  You can check for the output format and related things in the online manual page.

Comment: Using `libbfd` for _anything_ is the wrong advice -- it's a horrible library which should ~never be used.

Comment: that's a point of view.... noticed!  But IMHO downvoting an answer because of a taste or preference of use or a personal opinion is bad behaviour... Your comment should be sufficient.  Just to say that it is used in `binutils` package that is part of GCC compiler is enough to consider it's use.  Of coutse I'm in agreement with you that including a full library for just one thing is not the best approach.  But it is a good starting point for someone that has it's first entounter with ELF.

Comment: "But it is a good starting point for someone that has it's first entounter with ELF". No, it _definitely_ isn't. There are a lot of libraries which are a _much better_ starting point, `libelf` is one. `libbfd` is the _worst_ starting point you could suggest.

Comment: Your arguments are too heavy to be even considered.  you started saying that libbfd was not appropiate as it was large... now you don't even give a reason.  That's good arguing.  Thanks for the hint.  I'll never recommend this library again. We are learning a lot with your counseil